# .net Framework 3.1 SP1 does not continue to install

Tags: installation, .net-3.5

I am trying to install "dotnetfx35.exe" (offline installer) on my Windows 7 machine. When I run the installer it shows a window with some progress bar that says extracting. The problem is, when it reaches the 100%, it just disappear without error message and does not continue. I've already removed ALL .net frameworks, I paused my anti-virus, I run it as administrator, I've downloaded it again but no luck... What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking for the installation logs, they should contain more information about the failure.

How to find the log files:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/07/31/4156781.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/04/30/8445569.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/11/21/6458047.aspx